# Google authentication in ASP.NET Core without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, google-authentication

Is it any way to implement authentication via Google in ASP.Net core without ASP.NET Identity?
I have implemented authentication based on cookies like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

And I need to add Google authentication to project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course. Here is a summary of one way you could go about this.

You can call the OAuth2 authentication server APIs directly, and write custom attributes / handlers / filters in .NET to integrate with that functionality and control access to your resources accordingly.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

I believe the current endpoints that Google provide for their explicit grant / server authentication flow are as follows:

- Login: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
- Token: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
- Details: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

You can discover more details about the specific HTTP request and responses in the above link, but that's the general gist of OAuth2 for web server, as I understand it :)

Back in your core application you can then write custom handler / filter / attribute code to handle the authentication and redirection. Some example .NET core code can be found here:

https://ignas.me/tech/custom-authentication-asp-net-core-20/

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to know the same thing and couldn't find any answers on the web, so I cloned the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Security (v2.1)` repo to see if I could figure out how it worked. I believe this is what you are looking for. Add this to your `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs` file.

```
      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/login"))
            // You must first create an app with Google and add its ID and Secret to your user-secrets.
            // https://console.developers.google.com/project
            .AddGoogle(o =>
            {
                o.ClientId = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID";
                o.ClientSecret = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET";
                o.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent"; // Hack so we always get a refresh token, it only comes on the first authorization response
                o.AccessType = "offline";
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Events = new OAuthEvents()
                {
                    // There are a number of (optional) events you may want to connect into and add your own claims to the user, or handle a remote failure, etc.
                    OnRemoteFailure = HandleOnRemoteFailure,
                    OnCreatingTicket = HandleOnCreatingTicket
                };
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey("urn:google:image", "image", "url");
            });
```

If you want to intercept some of the events to add additional claims to a user, or store them off in a database to apply app level authorization, you can connect in to various `OAuthEvents`. I placed the following methods at the bottom of the Startup.cs file, inside the Startup Class.

```
    private async Task HandleOnCreatingTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Identity;
        // please use better logic than GivenName. Demonstration purposes only.
        if(user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.Type==ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value == "MY_FAVORITE_USER")
        {
            user.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task HandleOnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
    {
        // add your logic here.
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Finally, you will need to add a couple of controller actions. I put mine in an AccountController.cs file like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        if (User == null || !User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
        {

            // By default the client will be redirect back to the URL that issued the challenge (/login?authtype=foo),
            // send them to the home page instead (/).
            string returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"];
            returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "/" : returnUrl;
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Google", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }

        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [Route("/logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri="/" });

        return View();
    }
}
```

I also put a couple of simple views so that once logged-out, a user could click a link to return to home, or to login again or as another user, etc.

This seemed to work for me.