# ASP.NET - Problem with authentication: Manually added claim is missing in the next request

Tags: asp.net, authentication, claims-based-identity, .net-6.0, claims

I am currently experimenting with external login providers like Google Authentication in my ASP.NET application.

As you can see on my ***Program.cs*** i'am running .NET6.

After the Google-Login was successfull, the ClaimsPrincipal has exactly one ClaimsIdentity (IsAuthenticated == true). Now I want to add my own 'Custom-Claim' to this identity. The addition works without any problems, but the next request is missing the custom claim (all other claims by Google are there).

Here is the part of my ***Program.cs*** where I add the authentication:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];   
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture","picture","url");
});
```

Here is the configuration of the middleware pipeline in ***Program.cs***:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use((httpContext, func) =>
{
    if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
        httpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.XRequestedWith] = "XMLHttpRequest";

    return func();
});

app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
```

Endpoint for Google Login:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GoogleSignIn")]
public async Task GoogleSignIn()
{
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri =Url.Action("GoogleResponse")});
}
```

In the "GoogleResponse" method i add the mentioned custom claim:

```
//this method gets called after the google login has finished
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    
    var identity = result.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
    var currentSidClaim = identity.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid);

    if (currentSidClaim != null)
        identity.RemoveClaim(currentSidClaim);
    
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "Hi i am some claim, but i'll miss on the next request :("));
   
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

ClaimsIdentity after adding the claim:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/INdGy.png]

ClaimsIdentity on the next request (in the same controller btw):

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oft3e.png]

Whether I access the identity via "User.Identity" or "HttpContext.User..." makes no difference.

Really hope somebody can clear things up for me.

I hope I don't have to implement a large / elaborate ASP.NET Identity solution to solve the problem. I would be happy with a lightweight authentication.

**UPDATE:**

After some further tests it looks like it is not necessarily related to the specific Google login. Even if I create a second identity at login, it is gone at the next request.

I guess the authentication cookie is not updated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add claims after callback from the external website. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-and-update-user-claims)

Comment: In the linked article, added claims are stored by "SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync". This forces the creation of a new authentication cookie.

I want to avoid adding Asp.Net.Identity in a big way with IdentityDbContext and everything that comes with it just to store the claim to the User.Identity. It seems like such a simple task and the solution seems way too big for me.

Comment: Ok, then check the following answer, maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733338/8978576

Comment: Thank you a lot! Adding the claims in the OnCreatingTicket callback-method solved the problem for me!!!